# How to pass from jquery to DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

how to pass data from jquery to DataTables. 
i followed this [link](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) based on link created string.

```
var jsonString = '{"data":{"2G":[{"amount":"9","detail":"35 MB 2G Data , Post 35 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"1 Day","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"16","detail":"90 MB 2G Data, Post 90 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"2 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"28","detail":"160 MB 2G Data, Post 160 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"4 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"54","detail":"300 MB 2G Data, Post 300 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"7 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"78","detail":"310 MB 2G Data , Post 310 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"10 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"95","detail":"550 MB 2G Data, Post 550 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"14 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"125","detail":"700 MB 2G Data, Post 700 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"18 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"155","detail":"850 MB 2G Data, Post 850 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"21 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"179","detail":"1 GB 2G Data, Post 1 GB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"198","detail":"Hero Recharge : Get 1.25 GB 2G Data assured benefit (upto 3 GB 2G Data with hero recharge)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"199","detail":"2 GB Unlimted 2G Data, Post 2 GB your speed will be reduced up to 40kbps","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"249","detail":"3 GB Unlimted 2G Data, Post 3 GB your speed will be reduced up to 40kbps","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"205","detail":"1 GB 2G Data Day + Extra 1 GB 2G Night Data (12AM to 6AM)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"305","detail":"2 GB 2G Data Day + Extra 2 GB 2G Night Data (12AM to 6AM)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"395","detail":"3 GB 2G Data Day + Extra 3 GB 2G Night Data (12AM to 6AM)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"57","detail":"190 MB 2G Data, Post 190 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"98","detail":"300 MB 2G Data, Post 300 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"}]},"resCode":"200","resText":"SUCCESS"}';

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $amountlist = $('#amount');
    var $detaillist = $('#detail');
    var $validitylist = $('#validity');
    var $talktimelist = $('#talktime');
    var myData = $.parseJSON(jsonString);    
    console.log(myData.data["2G"]);
      var dataa = "";

    $.each(myData.data["2G"], function(i,dataElem) {  
    dataa+= '[ "'+ dataElem.amount + '", "'+ dataElem.detail + '", "'+ dataElem.validity + '", "'+ dataElem.talktime + ' "],';

         });

alert(dataa);
var newString = dataa.replace(/],$/, ']');
alert('[ '+newString+ ' ]');
var ss = '[ '+newString+ ' ]';
alert(ss);
var dataSet = [ss];
alert(dataSet);
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." }
        ]
    } );
} );



});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/5257/)

Comment: The data in their example is an array of strings not string of strings.

Comment: can you help how to create array of strings according to my code

Comment: `$.each` works on an array so I think you might already have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var jsonString = '{"data":{"2G":[{"amount":"9","detail":"35 MB 2G Data , Post 35 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"1 Day","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"16","detail":"90 MB 2G Data, Post 90 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"2 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"28","detail":"160 MB 2G Data, Post 160 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"4 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"54","detail":"300 MB 2G Data, Post 300 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"7 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"78","detail":"310 MB 2G Data , Post 310 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"10 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"95","detail":"550 MB 2G Data, Post 550 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"14 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"125","detail":"700 MB 2G Data, Post 700 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"18 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"155","detail":"850 MB 2G Data, Post 850 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"21 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"179","detail":"1 GB 2G Data, Post 1 GB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"198","detail":"Hero Recharge : Get 1.25 GB 2G Data assured benefit (upto 3 GB 2G Data with hero recharge)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"199","detail":"2 GB Unlimted 2G Data, Post 2 GB your speed will be reduced up to 40kbps","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"249","detail":"3 GB Unlimted 2G Data, Post 3 GB your speed will be reduced up to 40kbps","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"205","detail":"1 GB 2G Data Day + Extra 1 GB 2G Night Data (12AM to 6AM)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"305","detail":"2 GB 2G Data Day + Extra 2 GB 2G Night Data (12AM to 6AM)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"395","detail":"3 GB 2G Data Day + Extra 3 GB 2G Night Data (12AM to 6AM)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"57","detail":"190 MB 2G Data, Post 190 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"98","detail":"300 MB 2G Data, Post 300 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"}]},"resCode":"200","resText":"SUCCESS"}';
var temp_data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var array_of_arrays = [];

$.each(temp_data.data["2G"], function(i,dataElem) {  
  array_of_arrays.push([dataElem.amount,dataElem.detail,dataElem.validity,dataElem.talktime]);
});

console.log(array_of_arrays);




$('#example').DataTable( {
        data: array_of_arrays,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." }
        ]
    } );
```